# iTunes 11: Viewing albums by Date Added?

Tags: itunes, album

I buy music on a regular basis, so it's important to me to be able to see what albums I've just added to my collection. That way I can listen to my new purchases easily, without having to remember some obscure band name that's buried deep within my collection.

I used to be able to do this in the Zune software, is it possible in iTunes 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - just make an intelligent playlist with the following criteria:

- date added in the last week
- mediatype is music

don't forget the checkmark for refresh automatically at the end

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but still extremely useful and works pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: I use several playlists like this and instead of counting the time range, you can have a fixed amount of music play time or fixed MB/GB of space used. I find it nice to use these to get songs out of the cloud before a trip (and used them before that to sync a fresh/recent mix of songs each time the device was synced.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just right click on the top of the list, where it says Album, Artist, etc, and check 'Date Added'. This doesn't work in the album art view, but does work in the list view (the first two options).

This should work by song (its how the Recently Added playlist works), but most of my music is added by an album or single.

Comment: I've altered the question now, but it's worth noting that your answer didn't really solve my original problem anyway. Sorry! (When you're adding lots of albums at once, iTunes 10 would break them up by song anyway.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt, the Recently Added smart playlist allows you to filter for items added within a specific date range. Sorting the filtered items is a separate function accessible from the View > View Options menu, or by clicking the column header if you're in list view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late. Here's how you can view **songs** by date added in iTunes 12.3:

Go to Songs/Show columns/stats and click on "date added" (shown below)

[image]

After you do this, there will be a "date added" option on the top bar. Just click on it and you'll see all your songs in the order that they were added.